# Google Cloud Run only available in us-central1 region?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm creating a new Cloud Run service on GCP as part of an app that's going to have users in Europe and Asia, and I'd like to add corresponding Europe and Asia endpoints, but I'm only seeing us-central-1 in the location dropdown list when creating the service.

I could have sworn that there were options for Europe and Asia in that dropdown recently – am I wrong, or were they removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the beta version, only us-central1 is available at this time.

If you have signed up for the alpha releases, other regions are available. However, be cautioned that alpha can potentially be unstable. Details on alpha releases are not published on public forums.